# Finding the region of analitycity of $\sqrt{z^3 -1 }$

Tags: complex-numbers

let $f(z) = \sqrt{z^3 -1} $. I want to find where is $f$ analytic.

I can write $f(z) = e^{\frac{1}{2} \log(z^3 - 1)} $. Write $z = x+iy$. So, $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ (x,y) : x \leq 0, y = 0 \}$. We find the bad points of $f$. That is, the points of $z^3 - 1$ that lie on $\{ (x,y) : x \leq 0, y =0 \}$ So, we have to solve $z^3 - 1 = a $ for $a \leq 0 $. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are using the branch for square root that is discontinuous along negative reals? (That is, a $\log$ branch discontinuous along negative reals?) Then it seems like you are on the right track. With a different square root branch, things would be different.

Comment: I am using the principal branch of the logarithm function